# Task Scheduler in Windows 7 always treats computer as idle

Tags: windows, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I have a weird issue with one of the default Windows tasks, namely Microsoft/Windows/AppID/VerifiedPublisherCertStoreCheck

Here are its default settings:

```
Triggers

At startup
Delay task for 30 minutes, repeat task every 1 day indefinitely.

Conditions

Start task if computer is idle for 3 minutes
Wait for idle for 23 hours
Stop if the computer ceases to be idle
Restart if the idle state resumes
Start the task only if the computer is on AC power
Stop if the computer switches to battery power

Settings

Allow task to be run on demand
Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed
Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days
If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop
If the task is already running then queue a new instance.

Actions

Start %windir%\system32\appidcertstorecheck.exe
```

As can be seen, it's supposed to auto-restart every 1 day and also start if computer is idle for 3 minutes. However, for me, this task keeps starting every 3 minutes indefinitely despite the fact that I keep my activity for many hours straight. I specifically tested it: I kept moving the mouse, pressing buttons and doing something, and the task kept restarting every 3 minutes no matter what.

What can be the cause of this? How can I fix it? I've never changed the factory settings of this task, but it's kind of obvious that it's not the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Stop if the computer ceases to be idle" condition is selected for a task
and the task is running while the computer is in an idle state,
then the task will stop running when the computer ceases to be idle.
The task that is stopped by this condition will start running again the next time
the computer enters an idle state if the "Restart if idle state resumes"
condition is selected.

The idle state has been redefined in Windows 10. While in Windows 7 this was checked
every 15 minutes, in Windows 10 the idle check time may be as small as 30 seconds,
depending on other conditions.

This means that if you haven't moved the mouse or typed on the keyboard for
30 seconds, the idle state might be re-entered and the "Restart if idle state resumes"
condition will trigger the task again.

I suggest to delete the "Restart if idle state resumes" condition from the task.

For more information see the article
[Windows 10 and Idle Timeout](https://optionkey.blogspot.com/2018/08/windows-10-and-idle-timeout.html).

Comment: In the very title of my question, I've mentioned that it's on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried without "Restart if idle state resumes"?